# Passing HTML INPUT field ID to PHP completion program in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I want to pass the id of the INPUT field to the PHP file providing options. Here's my HTML & jQuery code. But the PHP program gets the id as `undefined`. Thanks for helping.

jQuery :

```
    $('.classfield').autocomplete({

      //define callback to format results
      source: function(req, add){

        //pass request to server
        $.getJSON("ajax/ajax_suggestions.php?id="+$(this).attr('id')+"&callback=?", req, function(data) {

          //create array for response objects
          var suggestions = [];

          //process response
          $.each(data, function(i, val){
            suggestions.push(val.name);
          });

          //pass array to callback
          add(suggestions);
        });
      },

      //define select handler
      change: function(e) {
        $("#spill").html("change "+$(this).val()+e.type);
      }
    }); // autocomplete
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="classfield" id="hello" value="there"></input><br>
```

Comment: you didn't add any HTML btw and there's some strange symbols in server url "...&callback=?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the id from `this.element`:

```
//pass request to server
$.getJSON("ajax/ajax_suggestions.php?id="+this.element.attr('id')+"&callback=?", req, function(data) {
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uN3ZC/).

Comment: You are welcome. It would be nice if you can accept the right answers of all of your questions (also see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).

Answer (score 1):

the value of `$(this).attr('id')` is undefined because `this` is the object that is put in the parameter of autocomplete (the parameter of autocomplete accepts an object, so if you use `$(this).attr('id')`, you are referencing the object that was passed in the parameter on the autocomplete)

therefore you cannot use `$(this).attr('id')`.

You have to store the id of the text field, may be as a global variable... Hope this helps a little bit